# C# deserialize unmanaged binary data with multiple struct members and struct arrays

Tags: c#, struct

I'm sure there is a easy answer, but I'm stuck. Been trying to understand deserializing unmanaged data structures into managed data and for simple structs everything is fine, but running into issues when the structs are more complex (Multiple member structs, arrays of structs, etc)

I tried Sequential, Auto and Explicit. Auto and Explicit throw errors, and sequential works but only on simpler types.

Below is my sample code. If I deserialize the binary data as `PacketHeader`, the info is correct. But If I deserialize as `BaseDataPacket`, it is not correct. Not even the `PacketHeader` even though it was when I did it by itself.

I would like to avoid doing explicit because there are potentially a lot of different structs I'd have to put offsets for, but I will if that is the only way.

**Main Struct**

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BaseDataPacket
{
    public PacketHeader Header;
    public PacketData[] Pdata;
}
```

**Packet Header Struct**

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack =1)]
public struct PacketHeader
{
    public ushort Format;
    public byte MajorVersion;
    public byte MinorVersion;
    public byte PacketVersion;
    public PacketType PacketId;
    public ulong SessionUID;
    public float SessionTime;
    public uint FrameIdentifier;
    public sbyte Index;
    public sbyte SecondaryIndex;
}
```

**packet data struct**

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct PacketData
{
    public byte d1;
    public byte d2;
    public byte d3;
    public float f1;
    public float f2;
    public float f3;
    public byte b1;
    public float f4;
    public float f5;
}
```

**And heres my code to marshal**

```
public static T FromBinaryReader<T>(BinaryReader reader)
    {

        // Read in a byte array
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));

        // Pin the managed memory while, copy it out the data, then unpin it
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        T returnStruct = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        handle.Free();
        return returnStruct;
    }
```

Any thoughts? Maybe this is a duplicate question i didnt find?

Comment: `PacketData[] Pdata`  is allocated on heap and not embedded within the struct, so there's no way to directly deserialize `BaseDataPacket` struct without manually allocating and filling the `Pdata` array.

Comment: C# has a feature called "Fixed Size Buffers" which does embed fixed size arrays within the struct, the problem is that it can only be used in "unsafe" contexts and C# doesn't do bounds checks on fixed size arrays. This is a design defect in C#.

Comment: Set `SizeConst` for `pData`?